# Rails: paginate_by_sql is listing repeated rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

`@stds  = Student.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page =>  params[:page], :per_page => 10)`  The sql is to list student details from multiple tables. The result contains a total of 18 rows. But the problem is some rows are repeating and some rows are not displaying. The first page is fine. The second page displays some rows which are already in the first page and skips some other rows. But if I display the whole thing in the first page itself by increasing the :per_page to 50 or something like this:> `@stds  = Student.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page =>  params[:page], :per_page => 50)`  then everything works fine(nothing is repeated and all the rows are displayed). Why is it so?

Comment: did you try using uniq ?

Comment: Post your `paginate_by_sql` method

Comment: I mean do you have a `paginate_by_sql` method

Comment: You mean a method defintion for `paginate_by_sql`? I have not defined any specific method for that

Comment: Ok Post your `Student` model

Comment: Are you using `will_paginate` gem?If so what is the version?

Comment: Yeah..that may be the problem. Let me check it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Pavan I am using `gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre4"`,  `will_paginate (3.0.5)`

Comment: Try finding the method `paginate_by_sql` in the gem and post the code

Comment: There is no such method in the gem

Comment: OK Try using like this `Student.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)`

Comment: It will list all the entries of Student table. But that is not what I need. I want to execute the sql to get a particular collection of students with their details from other tables. I have a written a query for that and its working fine.